# Construct space $Y$ such that $Y\times X$ is extremally disconnected for any Tychonoff space $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space. How can we construct a space $Y$ such that $Y\times X$ is extremally disconnected (Or Moscow) ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in general.  If $X$ is not extremally disconnected, then there is an open $U \subseteq X$ such that $\overline{U}$ is not open.  Then for any space $Y$ the set $Y \times U \subseteq Y \times X$ is open, and $\overline{Y \times U} = Y \times \overline{U}$ is not open in the product.  Thus $Y \times X$ is not extremally disconnected.

Comment: @ArthurFischer , Perhaps this problem could be avoided by adding conditions. I tried to answer the question when $Y\times X$ is a Moscow space, But I did not succeed.

Comment: Since retracts of Moscow spaces are themselves Moscow spaces and since $X$ is a retract of $X \times Y$ it follows that there can't be a space $Y$ such that $X \times Y$ is a Moscow space unless $X$ is already a Moscow space. // What is the motivation of this question?

Comment: @Martin : First, I am trying to solve [this Exercise 6.3.b](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358&dq=every%20compact%20space%20is%20a%20continuous%20image%20of%20a%20moscow%20space&source=bl&ots=fVNdS65_ud&sig=Fm0RqNKUht0Eh_vGx58MzVLtgz4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=75JJUcerKuiU0QXw1YDoDg&sqi=2&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=every%20compact%20space%20is%20a%20continuous%20image%20of%20a%20moscow%20space&f=false).

Comment: Also Every retract of extremally disconnected space is a extremally disconected space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, It is impossible. Since Every retract of (Moscow) extremally disconnected space is a (Moscow) extremally disconected space.